# How to use Snakemake for memory management?

Tags: snakemake

I tried to enforce Snakemake to run a rule (with many jobs) sequentially to avoid memory conflict.

```py
rule run_eval_all:
    input:
        expand("config["out_model"] + "{iLogit}.rds", iLogit = MODELS)

rule eval_model:
    input:
        script = config["src_est"] + "evals/script.R",
        model = config["out_model"] + "{iLogit}.rds",
    output:
        "out/{iLogit}.rds"

    threads: 5
    resources:
        mem_mb = 100000
    shell:
        "{runR} {input.script} "
        "--out {output}"
```

And I run the rule by `snakemake --cores all --resources mem_mb=100000 run_eval_all`. But I keep getting errors like:

```
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu % snakemake --resources mem_mb=100000 run_eval_all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/home/zhakaida/mambaforge/envs/r_snake/bin/snakemake", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/local/home/zhakaida/mambaforge/envs/r_snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 2401, in main
    resources = parse_resources(args.resources)
  File "/local/home/zhakaida/mambaforge/envs/r_snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/resources.py", line 85, in parse_resources
    for res, val in resources_args.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

If I run `snakemake --cores all run_eval_all`, it works but jobs run in parallel (as expected) and sometimes induces memory overuse and collapse. How shall I properly claim memory for Snakemake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to a known issue with parsing the `--resources` argument in Snakemake 6.5.1, https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1069.

Update to snakemake 6.5.3 or later and see if your problem still exists.

Comment: Or downgrade to 6.4.1 I guess :)